# Naming standard for namespaces and classes?

Tags: c#, .net, naming-conventions

In the following situation:

I have a set of projects that are plugins of an application. Each plugin has 3 namespaces:

1. Common
2. RealTime
3. Historical

Inside each namespace there is a class called Settings.

**First question**: how would you name this class, just Settings or CommonSettings, RealTimeSettings, HistoricalSettings?

Inside the Common namespace there is a class called DecisionEngine. This class uses 3 more clases, DecisionEngineData, DecisionEngineState and DecisionEngineDataSource.

**Second question**: would you leave the names are they are or would you try to find a way to avoid having the DecisionEngine prefix on all the classes?

Comment: Answers will be far too subjective for this to be a good question for Stack Overflow. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) notes: " Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site".

Comment: @J.Steen - For those reasons, it is not fit for Programmers either. Please read the Programmers [FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: @J.Steen - This is about naming conventions, not architecture or design patterns. Believe me - as an open ended question, it doesn't fit any Stack Exchange in its current form.

Comment: @Oded With some nudging, was my emphasis. However, I cede the point.

Comment: @J.Steen - I'd say you would have to nudge pretty hard...

Comment: This is a question about coding standards, I think it's very clear and can have a definite answer.

Comment: @Oded: so the thing is that I cannot make questions about naming-conventions because they are just a matter of taste ... why then we have a tag?

Comment: Lately I feel that there is an over-supervision of posts. I mean, does this REALLY matter? This question makes REALLY stackoverflow a worse place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's good practice to leave the names long and clear, so I would leave CommonSettings, RealTimeSettings, HistoricalSettings, DecisionEngineData, DecisionEngineState and DecisionEngineDataSource.

The thing with C# is that namespaces are usually not part of the code. Usually you just put `using RealTime` on top of your file, and then use just `RealTimeSettings` in your code. If the name of the class was `Settings`, the code would be less readable, because you would have to hover with your mouse over the class name in order to understand which namespace it belongs to.

Comment: I somewhat agree. I've tried using the namespace and does not fit very well what you usually see on other's code.

Answer (score 3):

I have often agonised over these sorts of naming issues. However, in actual use I've usually found that the longer class names actually makes the real code more readable. When you end up with a lot of classes called just "Settings", you have to keep checking which namespace it belongs to - or you have to fully qualify the name.

So I think you should keep the names you're already using.

But really, it's an ecumenical matter. :)